# Objective-c NSMutatbleArray addObject not adding

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Could someone help explain why the string "test" won't be added to the array??? The array appears to be null when I print it out in the NSLog call. I am new to objective-c and objective programming in general, and very confused. Thanks in advance!

```
@interface XYZ : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray *x;
- (void) doSomething;
@end


@implementation XYZ
@synthesize x;

-(void) doSomething
{
    [x addObject:@"test"];
    NSLog(@"%@",x);
}
@end



// main.m
#import "XYZ.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        XYZ *xyz = [[XYZ alloc] init];
        [xyz doSomething];

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the NSMutableArray.

```
- (id)init{

      x= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
      return self;
}
```

Comment: All the best. Go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add object in array you have to initialize that array. You have to initialize in your view did load or any where you want before adding some object on that array.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
      // your defult code 
      yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}
```